# realloc-ing a struct with flexible array

Tags: c

I ran into a rather weird problem,

I have the following code:

```
typedef struct{
    char *a;
    char *b;
    char *c;
}Str;

typedef struct{
    int size;
    str array[]; //flexible array.
}strArr;
```

The purpose here is to allocate a,b, and c for the new element from the realloc.

```
StrArr *arr;
int arrSize;
arrSize = 1;

arr = malloc(sizeof(strArr)+sizeof(int)*arrSize);
arr->size++;
arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(strArr)+sizeof(int)*arr->size);
arr->array[arr->size-1].a = malloc(sizeof(char)*75);
arr->size++;
card = realloc(arr, sizeof(strArr)+sizeof(int)*arr->size);
```

The question is: whenever `arr` is realloc'd to be one bigger, do you have to allocate memory for the strings of the new element? This code will fail if it is run because it gives me `glibc detected at the second realloc`. What am I doing wrong? `If i take off the malloc statement in the middle it runs.` Also, if i try a strcpy into arr->array[arr->size-1].a, it would segfault.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: should be `arr = malloc(sizeof(strArr)+sizeof(Str)*arrSize);`?

Comment: and `arr->size` not initialized.

Comment: You can't `arr = malloc(sizeof(strArr)+sizeof(int)*arrSize); arr->size++;` because even though you have made memory for arr you haven't put any values into it so you can't increment size because it doesn't have a value to increment.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous issues with this code, enough to suggest that whatever you're experiencing can't be reproduced. Nonetheless, there are sufficient problems to cause instability (i.e. segmentation violations). I'm going to assume you meant to use a lowercase `s` in `str` rather than an uppercase `S` in `Str`; it only makes sense that way. Similarly for the lowercase `s` (which should be) in `strArray`.

At which point have you assigned `arr->size` a value in order for `arr->size++;` to be useful? That itself is a mistake, but that's interlaced into another mistake:

> ```
> arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(strArr)+sizeof(int)*arr->size);
> ```

That turns out to be a major issue as you continue to use the uninitialised variable in critical pieces of logic, again and again, nonetheless, once that issue is resolved, the next mistake here is:

Anything that resembles the pattern `X = realloc(X, Y);` is suspicious. It's the `X`es. Those should be different. You're *not supposed* to just *replace the values* like that. I mean, it'll *work*, kind of... but it's not much more effort to do it properly, and unless done properly, this won't be `valgrind`-friendly. That should be a big deal to you, because `valgrind` is a tool that helps us identify memory leaks!

You should store this into a temporary variable:

```
void *temp = realloc(X, Y);
```

... and then you can handle errors, perhaps by cleaning up and exiting properly:

```
if (temp == NULL) {
    perror("realloc");
 /* free(X); // what would valgrind cease complaining about? */
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

... and replacing `X` with `temp`:

```
X = temp;
```

---

`sizeof(int)` should not be assumed to be the same size as `sizeof str` (whatever `str` is). Given the type of `arr->array`, I would expect `sizeof str` or, better yet, here's a nice pattern to keep in mind:

```
// X = realloc(Y, Z); or ...
void *temp = realloc(arr, sizeof *arr + arr->size * sizeof arr->array[0]);
// XXX: handle errors
```

---

> The question is: whenever `arr` is realloc'd to be one bigger, do you have to allocate memory for the strings of the new element?

The strings themselves should be in a separate storage location to the list nodes. What is this? Strings and list nodes, in the same array?!

I suppose it might make sense if by *strings* you mean *fixed-width, null padded fields*. Fixing the width of the field makes expressing the array in a one-dimensional space much easier.

Otherwise, you should keep your strings allocated *separately* from your list nodes... in a manner with which the down-stream programmer has *complete control over*, if I may add, is kinda nice, though you lose that the moment you use `realloc`, `malloc`, etc (and thus the moment you use VLAs, hmmmm!)...

---

> What am I doing wrong?

I think I've picked apart your code sufficing to say:

- Initialise **all** of your variables before you use them. In this case, there are some variables pointed at by `arr` which are used without first being initialised.
- Don't assume `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof (/*any pointer type*/)` have the same width. There are very real systems where this won't be true.
- Remember to use that `X = realloc(Y, Z);` pattern, followed by error handling, followed by `Y = X;`.
- I'm still not sure whether forcing down-stream programmers to rely upon `malloc`/`realloc`/etc and `free` is necessary, or even beneficial, here.

> Also, if i try a strcpy into arr->array[arr->size-1].a, it would segfault.

Yes, well... *there's that phantom `arr->size`-related issue again!*

Comment: followed by Y = X;

Comment: @OS2  check again